# minimal polynomial of an element

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I we have that $\alpha$ is the positive real root of $f=x^4-3$ then the splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,i)$ if I then want to find the degree of the extension of this splitting field then we may conider the tower law so that we have that:

$[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,i):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,i):\mathbb{Q}(i)][\mathbb{Q}(i):\mathbb{Q}]$

Now clearly we have that $[\mathbb{Q}(i):\mathbb{Q}]=2$ as the minmal polynomial of $i$ is $x^2+1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ but what is the degree of the miniaml polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$? Is is 4? I think that it must be but I am not sure how to prove this, any help in doing this would be great?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have set up the tower law, you need to show that $\alpha$ has degree $4$ over ${\bf Q}(i)$. It does, but it may be easier to show that $\alpha$ has degree $4$ over the rationals, and then $i$ has degree $2$ over ${\bf Q}(\alpha)$.

$\alpha$ has degree $4$ over the rationals because its minimal polynomial is $x^4-3$, which has degree $4$. This is the minimal polynomial because it is irreducible over the rationals. OK so far?

Then $i$ has degree $2$ over ${\bf Q}(\alpha)$ because it can't have a higher degree (since it satisfies $x^2+1=0$) and it can't have a lower degree (since degree $1$ would imply that this nonreal number is in a subfield of the reals).

Comment: Sure thanks that makes it easier to think about. Thanks for the help.